# How add push Notifications to my news app made in flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-notifications

I have managed to fully create my news app and it's even live on play store. But their's a problem that I cannot send notifications to the user's device.  I use this library newsapi.org for the news sources.
Please help me with this problem.

I am not able to think of any solution to this problem. I wan't you to help me with this problem.

Comment: Have you tried using [Firebase Messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firebase (FCM service) to provide push notifications for your application.

You can find and configure your flutter project with this [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/).